# Using src css in React public folder

Tags: html, css, reactjs

My React application imports a stylesheet located in the `src` folder with a `import './css/styles.css'` at the top of `App.js`.

In the public folder I've created a simple `/docs/index.html` file which is linked to from the React app but which is otherwise not part of the app and doesn't use any JavaScript.

In that HTML file's header, is there a way to define the link to the same `/css/styles.css` file located in the `src` folder (which would work both in development and in build), or do I need to define an independent stylesheet file in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/styles.css">
```

> The %PUBLIC_URL% placeholder in the file path will be automatically
> replaced with the correct public URL when you run your React
> application or build it for production.

After making these changes, the index.html file in the public folder will be able to reference the CSS file correctly, and it will work both during development and after the application is built.

Comment: This works if the css file is in the public folder, not in the src folder. The webpack documentation says that static files (such as images) can be imported into JS directly — does that mean I should import my `index.html` file into `App.js` in order to make it use the css file?